# How to send the old password of a user who forgot it?

Tags: magento, configuration, magento-1.7, email-templates

I need a solution to send the OLD password of a customer who click and enter his email address in Forgot your password page. The default email template send just a link inviting the customer to reset his password at the site's page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current password is saved as MD5.  You can't send them their current password.

Comment: Magento stores the Password as a one way hash (MD5). This is not reversible encryption. Any website able to send your password is likely storing it in plaintext and therefore is a hacker magnet.

Comment: Fiasco Labs, I never trust a website that can e-mail me my password :)

Comment: Yep, it's curtains for those websites when I find I've purchased from them, I make sure no credit card information is stored in my account, obscure everything else and write them off for e-commerce. Often a nastynote to the web admin as well. It's no longer the '90s where we could get away with this laxity. PCI-DSS buster actually, so the guy's Merchant Account provider probably would want to know about it to protect themselves from fraud.